# How to show instance of class within a class in UML?

Tags: java, uml

If you want to show, for example, that a class `Match` contains an instance of class `Game` and class `Set`, then do you just simply have them in the attributes or do you have a line to the classes representing that when the instance of `Match` is created then that also creates an instance of `Game` and `Set`?
Here's what I mean in code:

```
public class Match {
    private Set set = new Set();
    private Game game = new Game();

}
```

Comment: Think about how you will access those attributes. Use encapsulation:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm    Also, create a constructor

Comment: Im thinking how will I represent those instances in UML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both listing as attributes and showing as association (line pointing to another class) are valid and have exactly similar semantic.

Showing graphically rather than textually gives you opportunity to optionally present additional information: aggregation/composition, availability, ownership. Yet if none of this is present or important, the meaning is precisely the same and one can be replaced with another depending on what is more useful for you.

Answer (score 10):

This kind of relationship between classes is called **association**. Association is marked in UML with simple arrow:
[image]
We also have to types of association:
   1. **Composition** - when our class contains reference to the other class and other class cannot exist without our class.
For example Human *contains* Hand, Leg, Heart, Car conatins Engine, Wheels. 
This type of association is understood as *strong reference* in garbage collection programming languages.
[image]
   2. **Aggregation** - when our class contains reference to the other class and other clas can exist without our class, for example School *contains* Student.
This type of association is understood as *weak reference* in garbage collection programming languages.
[image]

Composition is definetly the stronger one.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I add: In garbage collected programming languages, a composition can be understood as a strong reference while an aggregation is a weak reference.

Comment: Thanks alot, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Good explanation! But I'd add example with objects: person <>---- address . (person has an address)